# How to add group field in django admin using custom user model

Tags: django

Django custom user model: I created a custom user model but if I open a user in the django admin, I cannot see the field to add the user to a group.

What will I need to add to my custom user model code so I can see the field to manually add a user to a group in the django admin?

For example I know if I want to see permission fields, I will add to my class UserAdmin:

```
fieldsets = (
    ('Permissions', {'fields': ('admin', 'staff')}),         
)
```

Answer (score 0):

just add group in fieldset permission

```
('Permissions', {'fields': ( 'groups',)}),
```